# Is there any way to make C# not complain about uninitialized variables that are actually not uninitialized?

Tags: c#, closures

I am developing a library that initializes plain-old data objects from data retrieved from SQL Server stored procedures. One of its methods is the following one:

```
public static T RetrieveCompound<T, U>(string cmdText, params Parameter[] parameters)
    where T : Header<U>, new()
    where U : class, new() {

    Box<T> headerBox = new Box<T>();
    List<U> details;
    Execute(cmdText, parameters, new Action<Row>[] {
        SetReferenceAction<T>(headerBox) +
        delegate(Row row) { details = headerBox.Value.Details; },
        delegate(Row row) { details.Add(row.ToObject<U>()); }
    });
    return headerBox.Value;
}
```

The third parameter of `Execute` is an array of `Action<Row>`s. Although no static analyzer can programmatically prove it, because of the way the `Execute` method was programmed, no delegate can be run before the ones preceding it in the array. That means that the delegate

```
delegate(Row row) { details.Add(row.ToObject<U>()); } // use
```

must necessarily run after the delegate

```
delegate(Row row) { details = headerBox.Value.Details; } // initialize
```

And, thus, the variable `details` will necessarily be initialized before it is used.

But C# still complains: "Use of unassigned variable 'details'."

Is there any way to make C# not complain about uninitialized variables that are actually not?

---

I am beginning to think C# is not for me.

Comment: @Andrey: Traditional ORMs focus on completeness, and, thus, create huge objects and class hierarchies spilled with lots of metadata. Instead, my library focuses on efficiency. For example, my library can process stored procedures that return several rowsets at once, which results in less server trips when requesting entities with several level of detail.

Comment: there are very different ORMs with different level of fatness. I am pretty sure that there is one similar to yours.

Comment: Would any workaround be easier/faster/simpler than just assigning it to null?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the usual workaround:

```
List<U> details = null;
```

Answer (score 3):

Initialising it to a null value is one way of going about it:

```
List<U> details = null;
```

Then you can assign the correct data to it when you need to use it.